# relationship between user and category OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend, october-form-controller, october-partial

how to establish a relationship between the user and the category?

**A category has more than one user, and a user belongs to a category**

I add category_id in the user table

on the frontend I display the list of users with the plugin [builder](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder)
**but I also want to display the category of the user**

I use the [RainLab](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-user) user plugin

Help me please,

thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems you need to extend user model and add `category` relation runtime

> You need to add this code to your plugin's boot method

```
public function boot()
{
    //Extending User Plugin
    \RainLab\User\Models\User::extend(function($model) {

        $model->hasOne['category'] = 'HardikSatasiya\Plugin\Models\Category';

    });
}
```

this code will add dynamic relation to user model so now you can use this relation directly like `$userModel->category->name`

> so now in list you can use below code

```
{% for user in records %}
    Email : {{ user.email }}
    Category : {{ user.category.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

if any doubt please comment.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy with [OctoberCMS relationships](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations#one-to-many). I think you have defined the relationship in your **`User`** Model, if not defined it first like below,

```
    public $belongsTo = [
        'catgeory' => 'YourPluginName\YourAuthorName\Models\Category'
    ];
```

> In place of **YourPluginName** & **YourAuthorName**, please define your author and plugin name.

After defining the relationship, you can retrieve user's category by `$user->category`

e.g. Suppose you have the first User then you can retrieve category by,

```
$user = User::first();
$category = $user->category;

//and now you can get the category name and all fields by $category,
//$category->title;
//$catgory->name;
```

And if you are using **twig** in the page, and you are showing users with `{{ user.name}}`(field may be different) then you have to just use `{{ user.category.name}}` (field may be different) and you can show category too.

I hope you will get categories with users. If you find any difficulty please comment.

Comment: hi chirag you added code With `Category` model and added again category relation in same model, I guess it should be `User` model , also `rainlab.user` is separate plugin so you dont wish to add direct modification to it ... its better to extend `rainlab.user` plugin so in future plugin update will not cause any problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it was a typing mistake. And I think questioner has already defined the relationship and he has no idea about retrieving user's category.

Comment: @LutteP.Okamango Great feeling happy for you :) please upvote & accept answer as a appreciation

Comment: yes Hardik is right because if Rainlab.User plugin get update then the code written on user model for relation will be lost so this relationship must be added on his custom plugin's boot method.